# BGE How do I get a objects location/Rot/velocity into a property?

Tags: game-engine

I am working on a space game, no gravity, no friction, just a ship and lotsa things to avoid (rocks/aliens) all logic bricks.

How do I send my ship's current (updated constantly) location or rotation into individual properties?   i.e. X, Y, Z, XRot, YRot Zrot

I want to use these numbers to determine my ship's current velocity and location, combine the results with a collison sensor and then I can determine/set whether or not the ship hit a rock/planet hard enough to explode.
(slow = bounce  ---fast = Boom ---real fast = Rock and Ship go Boom)

This screams to me to be a python solution but that is outta my league to write, i have had some success dissecting and reworking existing python tho...

thanks for any pointers/help

jd

Comment: If you want to do it all in logic bricks, I believe it is not possible. I'm fairly certain a python script must be used.

Answer (score 0):

With python a python script u can pass the values to a object game engine property to work arround logic nodes (i suppose).

```
from bge import logic
def main(cont):# cont = currentController
    x,y,z = cont.owner.worldPosition # owner = your ship
    cont.owner["Xpos"] = x # Xpos = object game property
    cont.owner["Ypos"] = y # Ypos = object game property
    cont.owner["Xpos"] = z
```

[image]